# High CPU usage on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, cpu-usage

I'm having high CPU usage by a process called "DataDetectorsAgent" Which seems to start randomly even when I close it using Activity monitor. my questions are:

What does this process do?

how can I stop/disable it if it's possible?

I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.4

**Edit:**

The process shows up only when running Mail.app, as for the console logs it shows only the times I killed it.
I have ~4000 mails in Mail.app and I didn't receive them all at once. Tried the reboot and permissions repair but nothing is done.

Comment: If you need to disable Data Detectors in Mail: `defaults write com.apple.mail DisableDataDetectors YES`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data Detectors are the little popup menus that show in email messages when you mouse over something like a time or date--they offer a menu to intelligently add events to a calendar or contact info to address book.

That process is an included part of OS X (it resides in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework), but it shouldn't be hogging system resources in normal situations. Did you recently add a gigantic chunk of data to your system? I could imagine it running in order to index a gigantic email archive or something.

Does the process show up when Mail.app is not running? Or does anything related show up in Console logs?

My approach to this would honestly be a reboot, a permissions repair (if for nothing more than the placebo effect) and see if it goes away after a day or two. The only other mention of this I found on Google was a German forum where I think everyone was building Hackintoshes.

Comment: The process show up only when running Mail.app, as for the console logs it shows only the times I killed it.
I have ~4000 mails in Mail.app and I didn't receive them all at once. Tried the reboot and permissions repair but nothing is done.

Comment: See if it shows up when using Mail.app in a different user account. That'd narrow it down to your specific set of data giving it trouble.

Answer (score 2):

We all have the same problems at our company. It sounds stupid but if you start up mail without any running network (airpot disabled and cable unplugged) the cpu usage is and stay normal. If you start up mail with a connected network cpu usage is >100%. It is not a solution but works for us.